# Change tableview cell background color when dragged

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna opt out dark mode for my tableview cell, but when I drag the cell to reorder them, it has a dark background color, there is no way for me to change it.

```
self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

setting overrideUserInterfaceStyle is not working

Comment: `self.view.backgroundColor = .white` should, given you have overridden the system variable, solve this problem.

Comment: If you turn on dark mode, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

change in your AppDelegate

```
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    guard let window = window else { return false }
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
```